# glInvalidateFramebuffer generate invalid enum - OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I setup a framebuffer with 4 color attachment and 1 depth+stencil attachment. I am able to invalidate the 4 color attachments with glInvalidateFramebuffer, but it fails with `GL_INVALID_ENUM` for the depth+stencil attachment.

I don't understand since the GLES3 documentation says invalid enum is generated when target is not a valid enum, but clearly `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` is valid.

Here's the code to invalidate the color and depth+stencil attachments:

```
glInvalidateFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _draw_buffers.size(), _draw_buffers.begin());

const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT};
glInvalidateFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 1, attachments);
```

`_draw_buffers` is a `std::vector` with the proper 4 color attachments.

Comment: On the face of it that looks like a driver bug, which device / GPU is this happening on? Does specifying GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT and  GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT separately work?

Comment: Happens on iPhone 6s, XCode 7.3.1 targeting iOS 9. Indeed using `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` and `GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` separately works even thought I attached it using `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT`. Oh well...

Comment: That should work. From the spec: "Including DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT in the attachments list is a special case causing both the depth and stencil attachments of the framebuffer object to be invalidated."